# 日本語に違和感: 他の人のQ&Aページに表示される「求めていた回答ではありませんか?...」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

URL例: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/82/%E3%83%90%E3%83%8A%E3%83%8A%E3%81%AF%E3%81%8A%E3%82%84%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AB%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B

[image: 求めていた回答ではありませんか? ruby のタグが付いた他の質問を参照するか、自分で質問をする。]

- 「ですます」「である」が混ざっていることに違和感
- 「他の質問を参照」: そのタグが付いた質問に求めていた回答がある確率は低いだろうに、と思ってしまう

原文例:

> Not the answer you're looking for?    Browse other questions tagged java android json gson or ask your own question.

Comment: そこまでの違和感ではないのと、賛成票が入ってないので改善案を考えるのは保留します

Answer (score 1):

適用済みです。

[Transifexでのストリングはこちらです](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40287212?comment=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.ja.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F145%2F%25E6%2597%25A5%25E6%259C%25AC%25E8%25AA%259E%25E3%2581%25AB%25E9%2581%2595%25E5%2592%258C%25E6%2584%259F-%25E4%25BB%2596%25E3%2581%25AE%25E4%25BA%25BA%25E3%2581%25AEqa%25E3%2583%259A%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2582%25B8%25E3%2581%25AB%25E8%25A1%25A8%25E7%25A4%25BA%25E3%2581%2595%25E3%2582%258C%25E3%2582%258B-%25E6%25B1%2582%25E3%2582%2581%25E3%2581%25A6%25E3%2581%2584%25E3%2581%259F%25E5%259B%259E%25E7%25AD%2594%25E3%2581%25A7%25E3%2581%25AF%25E3%2581%2582%25E3%2582%258A%25E3%2581%25BE%25E3%2581%259B%25E3%2582%2593%25E3%2581%258B)